# Typescript - Regex to check if strings contains vowels

Tags: angular, typescript

Can anyone help me to write a regex to see if the string contain vowels in it.

```
EX : Hi Team // True
     H // False
```

I am using using below regex but not getting required result.

```
[aeiou]
```

Comment: Don't you mean **vowel** ?

Comment: `var pattern = new RegExp(/[aeiouAEIOU]/g);
    var res = pattern.test("Your string here bla bla");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example to check for vowels

```js
const withVowels = 'This is a sentence with vowels';
const withoutVowels = 'dfjgbvcnr tkhlgj bdhs'; // I seriously didn't bother there

const hasVowelsRegex = /[aeiouy]/g; 

console.log(!!withVowels.match(hasVowelsRegex));
console.log(!!withoutVowels.match(hasVowelsRegex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```js
const regex = /^[aeiouy]+$/gmi;
const str = `aeyiuo
aeYYuo
qrcbk
aeeeee
normal
Text
extTT`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```